# run pygame with phycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I try to run pygame in Pycharm. The editor show the library. But if I run the program I get an error that it can't find the module: pygame.

I am running python 3.5

I added a picutre:
[image]

I try it like this:

[image]

Thank you

oke, I have done that.See:

[image]

So I run again the program:

see image:
[image]

ok. I am using python: Python 3.4.4.

but if I do this:

pip3 install pygame. I get this warning:

[image]

see image:
[image]

Comment: This is a python error not pycharm

Answer (score 1):

then install `pygame`:

```
pip install pygame
```

or:

```
python -m pip install pygame
```

or from code:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'pygame'])
```

Comment: He doesnt have pygame imported too so it may only make an error that the module is missing. Pycharm even suggests it

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not have the PyGame module and even PyCharm suggests it for you.
2. You do not run pip inside the python IDE. In order to do install a module with pip you have to open the command line and directly run

   `Pip install PyGame`

Or

```
Python -m pip install pygame
```

3. Based on previous answer on a question like yours: Are you sure you have got pygame for Python 3.5? The version for 3.5 wont work and produce this error msg, because the pyd file wont find the python 3.5 dll.

   EDIT: since you are installing for python2.7 USE PIP3 to install

   `pip3 install pygame`
4. Since pygame's pip page is rarely downloaded I suggest you download the module from BitBucket avaivable [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads).

Comment: Ok ignore my answer until I edit it for the 3rd thing

Comment: So you have it installed for python3 @SavantCode hmmmmm

Comment: You know. I can run all the 'normal programs' with packages like import random.., etc. But I just can't run pygame. I realy don't understand. I am using windows 10 - 64 bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123597/discussion-between-unknowndeveloper-and-savantcode).